# SWIG tutorial problems

Tags: python, c++, windows, visual-studio-2015, swig

I'm trying to follow the swig tutorial but I've got stuck, right now I'm using:

- Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  6 2015, 01:54:25) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
- Vs2015 x64, Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.23918 for x64
- SWIG Version 3.0.10

The contents are:

**example.c**

```
 #include <time.h>
 double My_variable = 3.0;

 int fact(int n) {
     if (n <= 1) return 1;
     else return n*fact(n-1);
 }

 int my_mod(int x, int y) {
     return (x%y);
 }

 char *get_time()
 {
     time_t ltime;
     time(&ltime);
     return ctime(&ltime);
 }
```

**example.i**

```
 %module example
 %{
 /* Put header files here or function declarations like below */
 extern double My_variable;
 extern int fact(int n);
 extern int my_mod(int x, int y);
 extern char *get_time();
 %}

 extern double My_variable;
 extern int fact(int n);
 extern int my_mod(int x, int y);
 extern char *get_time();
```

Then I do:

- `swig -python example.i`
- `cl /D_USRDLL /D_WINDLL example.c example_wrap.c -Ic:\Python351\include /link /DLL /out:example.pyd /libpath:c:\python351\libs python35.lib`

But when I try `python -c "import example"` I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_example)
```

Question, what's going on and how do i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the dynamic-linked module for SWIG should begin with an underscore, in this case `_example.pyd`. The SWIG generated Python file is looking for the module named `_example`, see beginning of that file:

```
from sys import version_info
if version_info >= (2, 6, 0):
    def swig_import_helper():
        from os.path import dirname
        import imp
        fp = None
        try:                                           # ↓ SEE HERE
            fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_example', [dirname(__file__)])
        except ImportError:
            import _example # ← AND HERE
            return _example # ← AND HERE
        if fp is not None:
            try:                      # ↓ AND HERE
                _mod = imp.load_module('_example', fp, pathname, description)
            finally:
                fp.close()
            return _mod
    _example = swig_import_helper() # ← AND HERE
    del swig_import_helper
else:    # ↓ AND HERE
    import _example
```

It is in fact the name of the C++ module that is wrapped by SWIG.